# Como hacer un Slider en Java como el de Twich

Tags: java, netbeans, slider

quería saber si hay forma de hacer este tipo de Slider en Java (Netbeans)
[image: Slider de Twitch]

Comment: Hay forma de hacer lo que sea, inténtalo y nos cuentas si te atoras para poderte ayudar con alo en concreto

Answer (score 0):

Yo soy bastante novato pero por si ayuda puedo sugerir trabajar con base de algun carrusel de [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/), no se si conoces esto, porque veo dificil hacer algo de ese estilo desde cero.

Comment: Oh, okay, entiendo, muchas gracias